# What's the class or id of the autocomplete suggestions pane?

Tags: forms, ajax

I'm doing a form with a fairly standard autocomplete_path textfield, like:

```
$form['the_field'] = array(
    '#title' => t('A title'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#autocomplete_path' => "path/to/autocomplete",
    '#description' => "Some description."
);
```

It's working fine, but I want to do some styling of the suggestions that show up in response to the user's type-in.  I'm trying to track down the id or class of this pane so I can add some css or whatever, but I can't find it -- the various browser inspectors keep closing when I try to look at the pane.  Does anybody know what this is?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element's id attribute is `autocomplete`.